# Closest multiplication value from array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have an array of integers and a number K is given, i need to find the closest value (also the elements of arrays) to K which can be generated by multiplying various numbers from array.

eg.
arr - 2, 2, 5, 5, 7
K = 30

Output - 2*2*7 = 28.

I can't think of any better solution than an exponential one where i make different permutation of elements and check for the closest value. Please suggest a better (may be dynamic programming) approach to solve it efficiently.

This is what i wrote :-

```
void findClosestValue(int arr[], int start, int end, int k, int& diff, int mul)
{
    if(start<=end+1)
    {
        cout<<"  start = "<<start<<"  end = "<<end<<"  diff = "<<diff<<"  k = "<<k<<"  mul = "<<mul<<endl;
        if(diff > differ(k, mul))
            diff = differ(k, mul);
        findClosestValue(arr, start+1, end, k, diff, mul*arr[start]);
        findClosestValue(arr, start+1, end, k, diff, mul);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Call for this function was :-

int val = 100000000;

findClosestValue(arr, 0, size-1, k, val, 1);

Comment: You should provide details of your efforts (in code) and then somebody may start discussion on how it may be improved.

Comment: I will give a hint. You are deciding participation of numbers in the process of generating K. Each number is labeled 0 or 1, and permutation does not matter. The complete search space is 2^N, N length of array. If the array must contain natural numbers, you can imply from it 2*2 must be less than 2*2*7, and must be greater and 2. This is homework problem, you should try hard to solve it yourself.

Comment: @Mai How is your hint any different from the trivial exponential solution?

Comment: By taking logarithms you can see that it is equivalent to a subset sum problem, hence it is NP-hard.

Comment: It's definitely NP-hard. There may be a pseudo-polynomial solution like there is for subset sum.

Comment: @interjay While doing dynamic programming, you are exploring the dependency between cases from recurrence relation to reduce workload a bit by not repeating old cases. OP mentioned he tried listing permutations, so my hint also reminds him that permutation is not the point.

Comment: Can the no be greater than k, i.e in terms of absolute value it is closer, or does it always have to be smaller?

Comment: @u_seem_surprised it can be greater that K, all that is needed absolute difference b/w result and K should be minimum.

Comment: Could you aslo provide the constraints, like array length, and makimum value of k, the maximum value of array elements? Like interjay said in the previous comments a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm is possible, i.e it's complexity would depend on the size of the input.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is a dynamic programming problem, however there are some tricks to it.

What you need to build up is a table, by product you can reach, of the position of the LAST factor that you needed the FIRST time you reached that value.  (In other words if you find two ways of reaching a value, you want to stick with the first.)  You build this table up with dynamic programming.

In your example of `[2, 2, 5, 5, 7]` with positions from `0` to `4` that table will look like this:

```
{
    1: -1,
    2: 0,
    4: 1,
    5: 2,
    10: 2,
    20: 2,
    50: 3,
    100: 3,
    7: 4,
    14: 4,
    28: 4,
    35: 4,
    70: 4,
    140: 4,
    350: 4,
    700: 4
}
```

Now you search through the table to find the closest value.  Which is `28`.

Now you read off the factors backwards.  You get `28` with whatever is at position `4`, which is `7`.  Divide by that and you had `4` at position `1` which is `2`.  Divide by that and you had `2` at position `0` which is 2.  And finally you had `1` when you started.  (The empty product is always 1.)

This solution **almost** works.  The problem is that your table will generally get very large, and almost entirely filled with values that are too large.  Given the constraint of integers, you should keep track of the smallest absolute value you reach that is larger than the absolute value of the target answer.  In this case that would keep your table down to this:

```
{
    1: -1,
    2: 0,
    4: 1,
    5: 2,
    10: 2,
    20: 2,
    50: 3,
    7: 4,
    14: 4,
    28: 4,
    35: 4
}
```

Not such a big win here.  But with larger sets this will provide a dramatic improvement.